# Check column header of a range and operate on cells of another range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 named ranges; `DbCrHdr` & `Transactions`
I want to parse through `Transactions` and if the column index of the cell OR the column index matches "credit" on the `DbCrHdr` array, then I want to turn that number into a negative OR multiply by -1, and remap/refeed that array back into `Transactions`, altering the sheet.

How can I go about achieving this?

[working google sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rV-NKIXKI22dVnys9e2YC3apuu4CKM3WUqvWVTjIJMI/edit?usp=sharing)

the attached google apps scripts file;

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

// Global Variables

// Set ss to active spreadsheet 
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Set sheet to the current active sheet 
var Sheet = SS.getActiveSheet();

// Get current sheet name and set it to sheetName  
var SheetName = Sheet.getName();

// Get range by name and set it to a global variable
var TransxnRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("Transactions");

// Get array of values in the search Range
var TransxnValues = TransxnRange.getValues();

// Get range by name and set it to a global variable
var DbCrRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("DbCrHdr");

// Get array of values in the search Range
var DbCrValues = DbCrRange.getValues();

/**
 * Parse through the debit-credit row and change the currency to negative if the header is credit.
 * 
 * 
 */
function NegativeCredit()  {
  var LastCol = TransxnRange.getLastColumn();
  var LastRow = TransxnRange.getLastRow();
  var NumCol = TransxnRange.getNumColumns();
  var NumRow = TransxnRange.getNumRows();
  
  /**
  Logger.log(LastCol)
  Logger.log(LastRow)
  Logger.log(NumCol)
  Logger.log(NumRow)
  Logger.log(TransxnRange.getA1Notation())
  Logger.log(TransxnValues)
  Logger.log(DbCrRange.getA1Notation())
  Logger.log(DbCrValues)
   */

  
  TransxnValues.forEach(function(row) {
    row.forEach(function(col) {
      // Logger.log(col);  
    });
  });

  for ( i = 0; i < NumCol; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < NumRow; j++) {
      Logger.log(TransxnValues[j][i])

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to find the column indexes where `credit` appears in the first row of `DbCrValues`:

```
creditIndexes = DbCrValues.flat().flatMap((cr, i) => cr === 'credit' ? i : []);
```

Then [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) column index in `creditIndexes` check every row.

If the row [is a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) and the value is positive, change the sign to minus:

```
creditIndexes.forEach(col=>{
     TransxnValues.forEach((row,ir)=>{  
       let val = row[col];
       TransxnValues[ir][col] = val > 0 && !Number.isNaN(val) ? -val : val;
     });
});
```

otherwise, keep the existing value.

### Solution:

Keep the global declerations and change `NegativeCredit()` to:

```
function NegativeCredit()  {
   const creditIndexes = DbCrValues.flat().flatMap((cr, i) => cr === 'credit' ? i : []);
   creditIndexes.forEach(col=>{
     TransxnValues.forEach((row,ir)=>{  
       let val = row[col];
       TransxnValues[ir][col] = val > 0 && !Number.isNaN(val) ? -val : val;
     });
   });
   TransxnRange.setValues(TransxnValues);  
}
```

**Additional References:**

- [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: is there way to keep this function running on the background? or if I add it under function onOpen(), will it somewhat achieve that goal? Thank you btw.

Comment: @sle7en yes it is safe to do both. If the function runs multiple times then nothing can go wrong. You can either create a time-driven trigger to refresh it every time or you can put in in the `onOpen` trigger so everytime you **refresh** the spreadsheet (refresh the webpage) the function will be triggered. I think the second one makes more sense but the final decision is yours.

Comment: @sle7en for the latter, you can have something like that: `function onOpen(){
  NegativeCredit();
}` and `NegativeCredit` will be triggered everytime you open the spreadsheet file.

Comment: Lovely, thanks a bunch man, will go with the latter per your suggestion